# Confusion while trying to comprehend the solution to a codingbat assignment

Tags: java

Here is the problem from codingbat.com that I am having trouble understanding the solution to.

```
Given a string, return a version where all the "x" have been removed. 
Except an "x" at the very start or end should not be removed. 

stringX("xxHxix") → "xHix"
stringX("abxxxcd") → "abcd"
stringX("xabxxxcdx") → "xabcdx"
```

Here is the solution they provided:

```
public String stringX(String str) {
  String result = "";
  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    // Only append the char if it is not the "x" case
    if (!(i > 0 && i < (str.length()-1) && str.substring(i, i+1).equals("x"))) {
      result = result + str.substring(i, i+1); // Could use str.charAt(i) here
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

If someone could break down the complex logic in the if statement, it would be really helpful. Does the negation operator(!) apply to the entire if statement or only to what's inside of the first set of parenthesis? That if statement is what's really confusing me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, let us reformat the `if` statement:

```
if (
    !(
       i > 0 
       && i < (str.length()-1) 
       && str.substring(i, i+1).equals("x")
     )
   )
```

`i > 0 && i < (str.length()-1)` checks that the element is between the two end indexes of the `String`.

`str.substring(i, i+1).equals("x")` checks if the current element has value 'x'.

Finally, the negation applies to the logical AND of the above 2 statements.

In plain English this would be, "Append the current letter to your string, either if it is at one of the ends, or if it is between the extremes and not equal to x".

Comment: Which is definitely the way it should be written in a large piece of code if you don't want team members to hate you. Readability >>>> concise code

Comment: So basically how you broke down the above, it's saying where `i NOT greater than 0` AND `i is NOT less than (str.length()-1)` AND `str.substring NOT equals "x"`.. So each one of those statements is negated correct?

Comment: Yes. It is basically `NOT (condition 1 and condition 2 and condition 3)`

Answer (score 2):

The above code would be the same as negating each part as in

```
if (i != 0 && i != str.length() -1 && !str.substring(i, i+1).equals("x")) {
  result = result + str.substring(i, i+1); // Could use str.charAt(i) here
}
```

Comment: Thanks TazMan, I think so too.  Of course you could even have multiple if statements if it makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String stringX(String str) {

    int len = str.length();
    String word = "";

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
        if (!(i>0 && i < len-1 && str.charAt(i)=='x')){
            word += str.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    return word;
}
```

Comment: please add some text description too

Answer (score 0):

i hope u will like the below code:

```
public static String stringX(String str) {
    if(str.length()<2){
        return str;
    }

    String sub_first = str.substring(0, 1);
    String sub_last = str.substring(str.length() - 1);
    String sub_mid = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < sub_mid.length(); i++) {

        if (sub_mid.charAt(i) == 'x') {
            sub_mid = sub_mid.replace("x", "");

        }
    }
    return sub_first + sub_mid + sub_last;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better Consider this Solution. 
The Below Solution is same as given by you with more clarity.

- StrHasChanged - Check whether String contains 'X'.
- Then iterate from second till last before character.
- if StrHasChanged is false return Original string OR return modified String.

```
public String stringX(String str) {
  String newStr = "";
  Boolean StrHasChanged = false;
  
  if (str.length() > 1) {
    for (int itr = 1; itr < str.length()-1; itr ++) {
      if (str.charAt(itr) != 'x') {
        StrHasChanged = true;
        newStr = newStr + Character.toString(str.charAt(itr));
      }
    }
  }
  
  return ((str.length() == 1) || (!(StrHasChanged))) ? str : Character.toString(str.charAt(0)) + newStr + Character.toString( str.charAt(str.length()-1) );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public String stringX(String str) {
    if (str.length() <= 3)
        return str;
    else {
        String c = str.substring(0, 1);
        String d = str.substring(str.length() - 1, str.length());
        String a = str.replaceAll("x", "");
        if ((c.equals("x")) && (d.equals("x")))
            return c + a + d;
        else if (c.equals("x"))
            return c + a;
        else if (d.equals("x"))
            return a + d;
        else
            return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here a beginner asks to explain the logic or give it in plain english/pseudocode. Not replace it with different code using alternative approaches, that is hardly more readable

Comment: It's a good idea to check the dates on the questions you're answering. This one is 5-years old.